# Extension of Windows Workflow State Machine at run-time

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine-workflow

In our application, we have a state machine workflow. We want to allow user to extend the existing workflow by adding new states with their customized activities. In order to achieve this, we are thinking to rehost the workflow designer, provide some required activities in the toolbox, that can be used by user.

Here, we want to have some control in extending the workflow, like do some process while moving in or out to a state. In order to achieve this, we thought of extending existing 'State' class and override some functionality. But unfortunately it is sealed class, so we can't inherit it :(

So, how to achieve this functionality where at run-time, user can extend the workflow and we have complete control on their activities?